# Squared transform in coord ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data where I think that y^2 ~ x. 
So, I want to plot y as a function of x with some transformed scaled for y.

```
N <- 100

ggplot(data_frame(x = runif(N), y = 20 * sqrt(x) + rnorm(N)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

`+ scale_y_square`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new transformation with `scales::trans_new` and to use it with `coord_trans`:

```
N <- 100
ggplot(data_frame(x = runif(N), y = 20 * sqrt(x) + rnorm(N)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_trans(y = scales::trans_new("square", function(x) x^2, "sqrt"))
```

Comment: You can either make a coord_trans call or you can use math functions to modify the `x` values but are you really sure you want to do both????

Comment: I'm not doing both?

Comment: I thought you were doing both and I couldn't figure out why.